# Ubuntu installation via Unetbootin

Tags: 16.04, unetbootin

I apologize if my question title isn't very specific; I was really struggling to find a good title.

So, my end goal is to install Ubuntu onto my Samsung laptop as a **replacement** to my current Windows 10.

I began by downloading the Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS ISO file. I then tried to follow the instructions in the installation guide by booting my laptop from a USB drive with the ISO file on it. I went into BIOS and made the USB drive first priority for boot, but when starting my PC up again it just completely ignored the USB drive and loaded windows as normal.

I then tried the Unetbootin approach. I restarted my laptop and selected to boot from Unetbootin. I was then taken to an Ubuntu interface - progress!

I then entered the installation file and the installation wizard opened.

However, I keep being taken to an **Installation type** window where I am being asked to select partitions. As far as I've seen from Google searching, this is only supposed to happen if I selected the **Something else** installation type option. But that's just it - I'm not being given the option to **Erase disk and install Ubuntu**.

If anyone has any pointers as to how I can get Ubuntu properly installed and replace my Windows 10, that'd be amazing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to try creating the image with another tool. RUFUS if you are in Windows https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale  ETCHER  If you do it on Linux (although it can also be used from Windows) https://etcher.io/

Comment: Cloning is a reliable method, and in Windows you can clone from the iso file to a USB boot drive with [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb). In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions you can use the built-in **Startup Disk Creator** or install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). See the following link for more details, [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: Unetbootin is old and unreliable IMHO - use Rufus instead, as described here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Thanks! Rufus was definitely the right way to go. I did have some issues afterwards with the flash drive not showing in bios, but I did some searching and managed to rectify it by changing a few bios settings.